# Counting duplicates across multiple columns in excel

Tags: excel, duplicates

I have a spreadsheet that looks like this

| State | City |
| --- | --- |
| WA | Seattle |
| WA | Seattle |
| WA | Yakama |
| OR | Portland |
| OR | Albany |
| NY | Albany |
| OR | Portland |

I want to count the duplicates but only for the times that BOTH columns are the same value, I would like the output to give me this info

| State | City | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| WA | Seattle | 3 |
| WA | Yakama | 1 |
| OR | Portland | 2 |
| OR | Albany | 1 |
| NY | Albany | 1 |

I know this should be simple but I am having trouble finding this exact question elsewhere... thanks

Comment: Would it help to create a 3rd column that's the concatenation of both first and to count duplicates from there ?

Comment: use a pivot table.

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple options.

**Solution 1: Formulas**

First copy and paste your state and city to new columns, then dedupe them using the Data tab. Then here's the formula for cell F3:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,D3,B:B,E3)
```

**Solution 2: Pivot Table**

Create a pivot off your data. Rows would be State and City. Values is Count of Whatever (city for example). Change your design to Tabular, repeat all labels, do not show grand or subtotals.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun a Microsoft365 solution (assuming you made a typo in your sample data):

[image]

```
=CHOOSE({1,2,3},UNIQUE(A2:B8),INDEX(UNIQUE(A2:B8),0,2),COUNTIFS(A2:A8,INDEX(UNIQUE(A2:B8),0,1),B2:B8,INDEX(UNIQUE(A2:B8),0,2)))
```

Comment: `{1,2,3}` would be the correct in EN-US format.